# Python interpolation of 3D points

Tags: python, 3d, interpolation, point

I have problem with interpolation of 3D data points in Python.
I have simple data structure like this:

```
class Point( object ):
def __init__( self, x, y, z, data ):
    self.x, self.y, self.z = x, y, z
    self.data = data
```

x,y,z are coordinates in 3D cartesian space, data is scalar value at this point.

I was trying method shown here: [Interpolation/subsampling of 3D data in python without VTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15748767/interpolation-subsampling-of-3d-data-in-python-without-vtk), but I had problem to get it working correctly.

Comment: Where is your code?  In what way(s) is it incorrect?

Comment: Note that you are actually trying to interpolate 4D points (x,y,z,v) so you are probably going to have to look at slices through the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the scipy's interpolate function. The first answer by unutbu does exactly that. Alternatively you could learn about the function here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html